# Using a static property defined in subclass from superclass

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I want to define a static property in the sub class, and access it in the super class. Is that possible?

The error message reads: `model is not defined`.

I just want my FieldsetController to know about the model `Fieldset`:

```
import Model from './../../library/Model'

class Fieldset extends Model {
  static name = 'fieldset'
  static pluralName = 'fieldsets'
}

export default Fieldset
```

The code looks like:

fieldset/controller.js:

```
import Controller from './../../library/controller'
import Fieldset from './model'

class FieldsetController extends Controller {
  static model = Fieldset
}

export default FieldsetController
```

library/controller.js:

```
class Controller {
  static index(request, response) {
    const data = model.getAll()
    response.render(`admin/${model.pluralName}/index`)
  }

  static create(request, response) {}

  static store(request, response) {}

  ...
}

export default Controller
```

Comment: Why? There is absolutely something wrong with your *requirement*! Explain exactly what you are trying to achieve, so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access static property from every place in your code:

```js
const model = FieldsetController.model;
```

Static members (properties or method) are characterized by fact that they are not binded to any instance of class. They can be access without invoking `new Class()`, and moreover, they cannot be accessed through instance.

**UPDATE**

As @Mohammad Dehghan wrote in comment there will be problem of circular dependencies which you should avoid. So better approach would be to remove **static** modifiers, and pass model to **super** function:

```
class FieldsetController extends Controller {
  model = Fieldset

  constructor() {
    super(this.model)
  }
}
```

And then you need to define it in parent class contructor:

```js
class Controller {
  model;
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  index(request, response) {
    // here you can get model
    const data = this.model.getAll()
    response.render(`admin/${model.pluralName}/index`)
  }
}
```

When you want to invoke index method you need to initialize FieldsetController class:

```js
const controller = new FieldsetController();
controller.index();
```

Comment: In his code, OP needs to reference module "library/controller" to "fieldset/controller" for that purpose, and that's dangerous because it creates circular dependencies.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan, of course you are right. I've missed that. Just updated my answer